# PHP MySQL make insert and update large amount of users faster

Tags: php, mysql

I'am using php on server side to manage data with MySQL. I have to request a API that gives me an list of users. I need to check for each user if he is in the database. If yes, I update his information. If not, I insert him in the data base.

The issue is that there is more than 2000+ users each times and my code in PHP is really slow (sometimes I get 504 Gateway Time-out). We will have even more users very soon.

How can I make my code faster ? Is Php ok if there is more users?

```
    $userList = getFromAPI();

      foreach ($userList as $userId){

        $db = dbConnect();

  $query = $db->prepare(
      "SELECT openid FROM USERS WHERE openid = :openid"
    );

  $query->execute([
    "openid"=>$openId,
    ]);

    $res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $tagList = implode(",", $user["tagid_list"]);

        if (!empty($res)) {

          $query = $db->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO USERS(id, name, group) VALUES(:id, :name, :group)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=:name, group=:group"
          );

          $query->execute([
        "id"=>$id,
        "name"=>$name,
        "group"=>$group
          ]);
        }

     }
```

Comment: This code is extremely inconsistent. I don't see where $openId or $user or $group are ever coming from.  and there is an error in the query.Care to make this code a *real one*?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the key point would be to **wrap all your inserts in a transaction** [to make them dramatically faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531678/slow-performance-mysql).

Other points of less significance but rather a matter of sanity are:

- connect **once**
- prepare **once** and also make sure you are using a [non-emulated prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiexec)
- get rid of the useless SELECT

So it should be like

```
$db = dbConnect();
$query = $db->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO USERS(id, name, `group`) VALUES(:id, :name, :group)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=values(name), group=values(`group`)"
);

$userList = getFromAPI();
$db->beginTransaction();
foreach ($userList as $userId){
    // assuming you have a code to define these variables 
    $query->execute([
    "id"=>$id,
    "name"=>$name,
    "group"=>$group
      ]);
}
$db->commit();
```